# Prisma Select produces a TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a Prisma model to define a booking.

```
model Booking {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  people           Int
  time             DateTime
  user_id          Int
  booker           User             @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  booker_occasion  String
  booker_request   String
  restaurant_id    Int
  restaurant       Restaurant       @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
  created_at       DateTime         @default(now())
  updated_at       DateTime         @updatedAt
  tables BookingOnTable[]
}
```

And I'm using a Prisma select statement to fetch this data.

```
select: {
      id: true,
      people: true,
      time: true,
      tables: true,
      user_id: true,
    },
```

However, this is producing a TypeScript error on the `tables` property.

```
Type '{ id: true; people: true; time: true; tables: true; user_id: true; }' is not assignable to type 'BookingSelect'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tables' does not exist in type 'BookingSelect'.ts(2322)
```

Here's the full code to attempt this:

### TypeScript

```
  const bookings = await prisma.booking.findMany({
    where: {
      time: {
        gte: new Date(`${dataParams.date}, ${searchTimes[0]}`),
        lte: new Date(
          `${dataParams.date}, ${searchTimes[searchTimes.length - 1]}`
        ),
      },
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      people: true,
      time: true,
      tables: true,
      user_id: true,
    },
  });
```

### Prisma Schema

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Restaurant {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  main_img    String
  images      String[]
  description String
  price       PRICE
  opens_at    String
  closes_at   String
  slug        String    @unique
  created_at  DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime  @updatedAt
  item        Item[]
  location_id Int       @unique
  location    Location  @relation(fields: [location_id], references: [id])
  cuisine_id  Int       @unique
  cuisine     Cuisine   @relation(fields: [cuisine_id], references: [id])
  review_id   Int       @unique
  reviews     Review[]
  booking     Booking[]
  table       Table[]
}

model Item {
  id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  price         String
  description   String
  created_at    DateTime   @default(now())
  updated_at    DateTime   @updatedAt
  restaurant_id Int
  restaurant    Restaurant @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
}

model Location {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  restraunts Restaurant[]
  created_at DateTime     @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime     @updatedAt
}

model Cuisine {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  restraunts Restaurant[]
  created_at DateTime     @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime     @updatedAt
}

model User {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name String
  last_name  String
  city       String
  email      String    @unique
  password   String
  phone      String
  review     Review[]
  created_at DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime  @updatedAt
  booking    Booking[]
}

model Review {
  id            Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name    String
  last_name     String
  rating        Float
  text          String
  restaurant_id Int
  restaurant    Restaurant @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
  user_id       Int
  user          User       @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  created_at    DateTime   @default(now())
  updated_at    DateTime   @updatedAt
}

model Booking {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  people           Int
  time             DateTime
  user_id          Int
  booker           User             @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  booker_occasion  String
  booker_request   String
  restaurant_id    Int
  restaurant       Restaurant       @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
  created_at       DateTime         @default(now())
  updated_at       DateTime         @updatedAt
  tables BookingOnTable[]
}

model Table {
  id             Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  restaurant_id  Int
  restaurant     Restaurant       @relation(fields: [restaurant_id], references: [id])
  created_at     DateTime         @default(now())
  updated_at     DateTime         @updatedAt
  booking_on_table BookingOnTable[]
}

model BookingOnTable {
  booking_id Int
  booking    Booking @relation(fields: [booking_id], references: [id])
  table_id   Int
  table      Table   @relation(fields: [table_id], references: [id])
  created_at       DateTime         @default(now())
  updated_at       DateTime         @updatedAt

  @@id([booking_id, table_id])
}

enum PRICE {
  CHEAP
  REGULAR
  HIGH
  EXPENSIVE
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Have you updated the TypeScript types after changing your schema with `prisma generate` (add `npx`, `yarn`, or `pnpm` to the start if you don't have prisma installed globally)?

Comment: Yes I have Prisma installed and I've pushed it to my database using ```npx prisma db push``.`

Answer (score -1):

Relations in prisma are queried using `include` instead of `select`

```
include: {
    tables: true
}
```

[Docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#include)

Comment: Would I still be able to use my ```select``` query?

Comment: @Ethan Prisma only lets you choose one of them. Also, it looks like in newer versions you can, in fact, query relations with `select`. Can you specify, which version of prisma are you using?

Comment: @Ethan I copied your prisma schema and I did not get the same error, it worked just fine. You probably forgot to run `npx prisma generate` to generate client-side typescript types.